# How to avoid OutOfMemoryException on async methods that each consumes a lot of memory?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, memory, async-await, out-of-memory

I am trying to process some list of items that are expanded significantly when read. I process them in async functions, so it might happen that at some point, there will be too many functions running and throwing OutOfMemoryException.

I was thinking about restricting the amount of simultaneous tasks that are running and not completed according to some hard limit. But I can't really predict how many tasks are too few/many because each item might expand differently.

Is there some smart way to avoid exception here without introducing a hard limit?

Example to provoke the behavior:

```
void Main()
{        
    Int32 million = 1000000;    
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Task t = Do(million);
        tasks.Add(t);
    }   
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}


public static async Task Do(Int32 count)
{
    //I tried 'await Task.Yield()' here; didn't help.

    //consume memory
    StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        dataBuilder.Append(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
    String data = dataBuilder.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"here [{data.Length}]");
    //do I/O
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Task.Run`? The way this is coded, you are creating a string in the original thread before yielding. `await` doesn't make anything run asynchronously by magic, it only allows you to use the `await` keyword to await an already asynchronous operation

Comment: As for the OOM exception, are you running in 32 or 64-bit? Allocating such large objects can lead to such memory fragmentation after a while that the allocator can't find a single memory block to use.

Comment: Even worse, by adding data bit by bit, StringBuilder has to allocate *new* buffers each time the previous one is filled. Reallocation is performed by allocating a buffer twice as large as the old one and copying the data. This can waste a **LOT** of memory for just a single big string. Since you already know the size of the final string, specify it when creating the SringBuilder, eg `new StringBuilder(36*count);`

Comment: You can use `BenchmarkDotNet` to check the GC and memory performance of different options. I suspect you'll be surprised by the effects of reallocation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Regarding the StringBuilder comment - this is just an example to provoke the problem. I don't use stringbuilder in my original case. Notice my comment that I tried Task.Yield as well, so it shouldn't necessarily run on the same thread. I also tried Task.Run after your comment to make sure it didn't run on original thread. But it doesn't make a difference. I'm asking if there is any built-in functionality that can self-regulate on this case, or if I am forced to manually check current memory state or introduce a hard limit on how many tasks I initiate.

Comment: `Task.Yield` yields. It doesn't schedule anything to run. As for the memory problem, you are allocating 20 strings, 36M bytes long with at least 10 reallocations for each - that's a lot of strings. The GC doesn't have a chance to run, and even if it did, it couldn't clean up that many large objects fast enough. It's no wonder you end up with an OOM in the end. Memory fragmentation is enough to cause this

Comment: there is not much you can do about out of memory exception, except if you separate your list into smaller chunks, note that the list size it self is limited to around 2gb, it cant be more even on 64bit process on computer with tons of memory.

Comment: Running out of memory has two solutions: 1.  buy more, or 2. use less.  In this case I think you'd get a LOT more performance by re-writing your algorithm as a stream processor that acts on only a small part of the data at a time.  The quintessential example is a string parser that only ever holds one character in memory at a time.

Comment: You could try parallel foreach, that would limit the number of tasks executing at once.  Basically, you're trying to do too much at once.  Alternative, as has been suggested, don't try to use so much in memory.  Refactor to using a `Stream`, then you can switch to a `FileStream` or something.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Unfortunately I think my example was too abstract to communicate my question, and perhaps it doesn't even reproduce the problem faithfully in that it gets OutOfMemoryException because of fragmentation instead of actual memory limit. I just wanted to reproduce a problem where it doesn't crash in one instance, but crashes in multiple instances. huge strings doesn't have anything to do with my real problem where I have tons of smaller objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use streaming style instead of giant buffer style code.

```
public static async Task Do(Int32 count)
{
    //I tried 'await Task.Yield()' here; didn't help.

    //consume memory
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }

    //do I/O
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

The idea is to not buffer all of your output and send it at the end, but rather, send it on its way as it's being created (to file, network, frame buffer, whatever).